# ERROR {...} does not match type string when adding expression with jscodeshift

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, jscodeshift

I am trying out jscodeshift and I keep getting the following error whenever I try to insert a new expression

```
{operator: ==, left: [object Object], right: [object Object], loc: null, type: BinaryExpression, comments: null} does not match type string
```

This is what is in my small test:

```
  var testBinary = j.binaryExpression("==", j.literal(2), j.literal(3))

  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.IfStatement)
    .insertBefore(testBinary)
    .toSource();
```

You can try it out it here https://astexplorer.net/#/P6euf9XIlR/1

if I use j(file.source).find().replaceWith() it works with no problem whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That actually looks like bug, or at least something that I need to investigate more. Please file an issue at https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift .

Comment: I've failed an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift/issues/161

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var testBinary = j.binaryExpression("==", j.literal(2), j.literal(3)),
  root = j(j(file.source);


    j(root.find(j.IfStatement).at(0).get())
    .insertBefore(testBinary);

    return root.toSource();
```